# Where to implement Layer normalization?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, normalization, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement Layer normalization on my LSTM model but I am unsure of how many Layer norms I need in my model and where to exactly place them

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    layers = [100, 200, 2]
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
        layers[0],
        input_shape=(timestep, feature),
        dropout=0.4, 
        recurrent_dropout=0.4,  
        return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(LayerNormalization())
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
        layers[1], 
        input_shape=(timestep, feature),
        dropout=0.4, 
        recurrent_dropout=0.4, 
        return_sequences=False)))
    model.add(LayerNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(
        layers[2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Normalization layers usually apply their normalization effect to the previous layer, so it should be put in front of the layer that you want normalized.

Usually all layers are normalized, except the output layer, so the configuration you are showing in your question already does this, so it can  be considered to be good practice.

In general you do not have to normalize every layer, and it is a bit of experimentation (trial and error) about which layers to normalize.